installation of libmozjs on 24.04 (noble numbat)
libmozjs185-dev seems to be missing in noble.
what do i install instead?
see also https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/install/unix.html#dependencies

To install SpiderMonkey JavaScript library in Ubuntu 24.04 open the terminal and type:
sudo apt install libmozjs-115-dev

In the link in your question it says;

You can install the dependencies by running:
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends -y install \
    build-essential pkg-config erlang \
    libicu-dev libmozjs185-dev

Be sure to update the version numbers to match your system’s available
packages.

The latest version available package in Ubuntu 24.04 is libmozjs-115-dev. The other four dependency packages are also available in the Ubuntu 24.04 default repositories.

The author commented that he needs a later version of CouchDB. Run these commands to install CouchDB from the official CouchDB package repository.
sudo apt install -y curl apt-transport-https gnupg
curl https://couchdb.apache.org/repo/keys.asc | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/couchdb-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null 2>&1
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/couchdb-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/couchdb-deb/ $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchdb.list >/dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install couchdb

During the installation, you will be prompted to set a password for the admin user and a magic cookie. Choose strong passwords for both.

by the author :
couchdb for kubuntu 24.04 requires libmozjs-185-dev, but a libmozjs-115-dev version (supplied with kubuntu 24.04) is being worked on at https://github.com/apache/couchdb/pull/5321/commits/9f1f1f32fc3956905fe999ab2fb79d9b93c4a760
